# How to Load test with Node JS and Mongo DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jmeter, integration-testing

How to Load test with NodeJS and MongoDB using Jmeter?
We need to Evaluate NodeJS and Mongo Db Performance?

Answer (score 5):

As like any web application you can loadtest NodeJS application via web services or URLs.

 You can use Jmeter Test Script recorder to record all requests and services of NodeJS app. If you need java script specific you can use [phanos](https://www.npmjs.org/package/phanos) or [Loadtest](https://www.npmjs.org/package/loadtest).
To load test mongo DB, since jmeter 2.9 there is a MongoDB sampler.